# To include values from n+1 row to n row in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck whereby there is an existing view table that was created and I have to enhance the existing view.

The previous **simplified/part** of the SQL query was as follows

```
SELECT
    mb.ID,
    mb.EffectiveDate,
    mb.Code
FROM 
    [dbo].[V_table1] mb
```

The following **simplified** output would be given as below

```
|  ID  |    EffectiveDate   | Code |
+------+--------------------+------+
| 1234 |     2018-06-14     |  B1  |
| 1234 |     2018-05-14     |  B2  |
| 1234 |     2018-04-14     |  B3  |
| 1235 |     2018-05-14     |  B2  |
```

I would like the following output to be like this

```
|  ID  |    PrevEffectiveDate   | Code |     EffectiveDate      | Code |
+------+------------------------+------+------------------------+------+
| 1234 |       2018-05-14       |  B2  |      2018-06-14        |  B1  |
| 1234 |       2018-04-14       |  B3  |      2018-05-14        |  B2  |
| 1234 |         NULL           | NULL |      2018-04-14        |  B3  |
| 1235 |         NULL           | NULL |      2018-05-14        |  B2  |
```

I have tried to use the `row_number()` function which will return 1 and 2 and 3 and so on.

However I could not use the temp tables as these are view tables and there are a lot of data there. Therefore would appreciate any assistance in solving this problem.

I have tried the following query and manage to get the out as below

Current query:

```
SELECT
    mb.ID,
    mb.EffectiveDate,
    mb.Code
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mb.ID ORDER BY mb.EffectiveDate DESC) AS row
FROM 
    [dbo].[V_table1] mb
```

Partial output:

```
|  ID  |    EffectiveDate   | Code | row |
+------+--------------------+------+-----+
| 1234 |     2018-06-14     |  B1  |  1  |
| 1234 |     2018-05-14     |  B2  |  2  |
| 1234 |     2018-04-14     |  B3  |  3  |
| 1235 |     2018-05-14     |  B2  |  1  |
```

Comment: `LEAD()` is an option here, if you are using SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I didnt know there was this function that i could used.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, you may try to use `LEAD()` (instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`) to get the values from the subsequent row:

```
SELECT
   mb.ID,
   mb.EffectiveDate,
   mb.Code
   LEAD(mb.EffectiveDate) OVER (PARTITION BY mb.ID ORDER BY mb.EffectiveDate DESC) AS PrevEffectiveDate,
   LEAD(mb.Code) OVER (PARTITION BY mb.ID ORDER BY mb.EffectiveDate DESC) AS PrevCode
FROM [dbo].[V_table1] mb
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `LAG()`:

```
SELECT mb.ID, 
      LAG(mb.EffectiveDate) OVER (PARTITION BY mb.ID ORDER BY mb.EffectiveDate) AS PrevEffectiveDate,
      LAG(mb.Code) OVER (PARTITION BY mb.ID ORDER BY mb.EffectiveDate) AS PrevCode,
      mb.EffectiveDate, mb.Code
FROM [dbo].[V_table1] mb;
```

This is pretty much equivalent to Zhorov's answer.  However, `LEAD()` with a descending sort just seems very, very awkward when `LAG()` does exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Common Table Expression you can achieve this as:

```
with a as
(SELECT mb.ID, mb.EffectiveDate, mb.Code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mb.ID ORDER BY mb.EffectiveDate DESC) AS row FROM [dbo].[V_table1] mb)


Select *,(select a.EffectiveDate from a where b.Id=a.Id and a.row=b.row+1) as PrevEffectiveDate,(select a.Code from a where b.Id=a.Id and a.row=b.row+1) as PrevCode  from a b
```